# Biblatex, apa-style, polyglossia and multilingual-bibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, sorting

For my scientific article I need to use some sources that are in Korean, which is why I've switched from using `pdflatex\bibtex` to `xelatex` and `biber`.

I've managed to get `biblatex` with `apa` style working (through other posts on this site). But I've encountered several problems so far and I am not sure whats causing them. 
I am facing the following four problems now:

1. The bibliography is not sorted (even though I used sorting=nyt).
2. If there is more than one source from one year, biblatex automatically adds an sorting system (by adding an a, b, c and so on), how can I disable this?
3. The issue of the journal is not displayed in the bibliography.
4. The text is not adjusted correctly, as can be seen in the pdf.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\thefield{#1}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldundef{#1}%
        {}%
        {\addcomma\addspace}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}\OR\iffieldundef{#1}}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongextra#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\thefield{#1}\printfield{extrayear}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldundef{#1}%
        {}%
        {\addcomma\addspace}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}\OR\iffieldundef{#1}}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongdmy#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldundef{#3}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{#2}\OR\iffieldundef{#3}}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \thefield{#1}}}}
\addbibresource{BT.bib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}                      % package for Korean fonts
\setmainlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setCJKmainfont{Dotum}              % For Korean font
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}           % Standard font
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Three main things when talking about IPO research: underpricing, long-term overpricing and IPO waves \parencite{Ka91}.
This is a test \parencite{Ro86,TiTr86, Ch99, Ch11}.

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

Here my .bib file:

```
@article{Ro86,
author = {K. Rock},
title = {Why new issues are underpriced},
journaltitle = {Journal of Financial Economics},
volume = {15},
year = {1986},
pages = {187-212}
}
@article{TiTr86,
author = {S. Titman and B. Trueman},
title = {Information Quality and the Valuation of New Issues},
journaltitle = {Journal of Accounting and Economics},
volume = {8},
year = {1986},
pages = {159-172}
}
@article{Ch99,
author = {M.-S. Choi},
title = {A Study on Initial Returns and Underpricing of {IPOs}},
journaltitle = {The Korean Journal of Finance},
volume = {12},
year = {1999},
pages = {197-226},
origlanguage = {Korean},
origtitle = {신규공모주의 공모가격 할인과 초기성과에 대한 연구},
origpublisher = {재무연구}
}
@article{Ch11,
author = {M.-S. Choi},
title = {Review of Empirical Studies on {IPO} Activity and Pricing Behavior in Korea},
journaltitle = {Asian Review of Financial Research},
volume = {24},
issue ={2},
year = {2011},
pages = {621-663},
}
@article{Ka91,
author = {H. S. Kang},
title = {An Empirical Study on the Effect of the Activities of Investment banks on IPO Pricing},
journaltitle = {The Korean Journal of Financial Management},
volume = {8},
issue = {2},
year = {1991},
pages = {31-45},
origlanguage = {Korean},
origtitle = {투자은행이 IPO의 가격형성에 미치는 영향에 관한 실증분석},
origpublisher = {재무관리연구}
}
```

Comment: @Audrey You might be interested in this one.

Comment: And maybe I should add something to my point number 1: In my original file (not the MWE), the first 25-30% of my sources are sorted according to the author name, the rest of the papers are sorted by year...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regard to question 3 (issue of journal not displayed), I quote section 2.2.2 (Data Fields) of the `biblatex` manual:

> issue
>
> field (literal)
>
> The issue of a journal. This field is intended for journals whose
>   individual issues are identified by a designation such as ‘Spring’ or
>   ‘Summer’ rather than the month or a number. Since the placement of
>   issue is similar to month and number, this field may also be useful
>   with double issues and other special cases.
>
> [...]
>
> number
>
> field (literal)
>
> The number of a journal or the volume/number of a book in a series.

Looking at your `.bib` file, I strongly suspect that you should replace your `issue` fields with `number` fields (which are displayed correctly by `biblatex-apa`).